# jquery buggy sort serialize

Tags: jquery, serialization, alert

i have discovered quite an odd behaviour of jquery. I have two lists here, where i drag and drop li-elements from one to another, the current sortings is being saved by ajax-mysql. Now this afternoon i noticed that sometimes, just sometimes the position of the last dropped item wasnt saved properly, it was saved as "0" when it should be for example 4 or 5. Took me some hours to find out that this behaviour is in direct relation to the alert, that is triggered after a drop of an item:

```
alert(data);       <---- data is the current sorting of the ids
```

If i remove this line, then the above described odd behaviour of the script appears. Maybe someone has experienced something like this before and can share some advise?

greets, Maschek

edit: This is the function, that contains the alert:

```
            $(function() {

             $("#sortable2").sortable({

                  items: \'li:not(.col_header)\',
            connectWith: \'#sortable2, #sortable1, #sortable1b, #sortable1c\',   
            helper: \'clone\',
            placeholder: \'empfaenger-highlight\',
         revert: \'invalid\',
         update: function() {

              var data = $(this).sortable("serialize") + \'&user='.$user.'\';

              alert(data);
              var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + 
              \'&action=updateList&user='.$user.'\'; 
             $.post("index.php?eID=moveitems", order, 
             function(theResponse){

                   $("#response").html(theResponse);
                   $("#response").slideDown(\'slow\');
                   slideout(); 

                 }); 

               } 

          }).disableSelection();
```

---

I tried to use a callback, to ensure the variable being loaded completely:

```
                    $(function() {

                     $("#sortable2").sortable({

                          items: \'li:not(.col_header)\',
                          connectWith: \'#sortable2, #sortable1, #sortable1b, #sortable1c\',            
                          helper: \'clone\',
                          placeholder: \'empfaenger-highlight\',
                          revert: \'invalid\',
                          update: function() {



                          var data = $(this).sortable("serialize");

                               function doSomething(data) {

                          };

                               //alert(data);
                               var order = data + \'&action=updateList&feuser='.$user.'\'; 

                               $.post("index.php?eID=moveitems", order,  function(theResponse){

                          }); 

                     }  

                }).disableSelection();
```

But the descriped miss-behaviour still occurs. Can someone tell me, if the use of this additional callback-function is the right approach? Or how else would i have to handle this, to ensure properly variable? thanks for your advises...

Comment: Can you show us more code? We need to know what the context of this alert is.

Comment: Why are you escaping single-quotes?

Comment: the code is within a php-file.

Comment: @maschek Ok, that makes more sense now.  I should have known from the dot operators on the strings.

Comment: @maschek It would be clearer, to me at least, if you should us what it looked like from a web browser's point of view (like right-click view source).  Then I wouldn't have to mentally transform strings and variables that appear plain-text already evaluated on the client.  It would also be helpful to see some sample html and possibly the request URL (plus POST data) that gets built by $.post.

Comment: I think i found the reason for this. I pass the variables via ajax to the mysql db. So maybe sometimes the values aint passed fast enough. If the alert is activated all the values are generated before transmitting for sure, because the alert is before transmitting, and the values are displayed in the alert already. at least thats what i assume atm.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, probably more easy to read from the output-code. The script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(
           function () {
                function slideout(){

                setTimeout(function(){

                     $("#sortable3 .provider, #sortable3 .empfaenger, #response").fadeOut("slow", function () {

               });

           }, 2000);}


           $(function() {

                $("#sortable2").sortable({

                     items: 'li:not(.col_header)',
                    connectWith: '#sortable2, #sortable1, #sortable1b, #sortable1c',            
                    helper: 'clone',
                    placeholder: 'empfaenger-highlight',
                    revert: 'invalid',
                    update: function() {

      var data = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&feuser=14';

      alert(data);
      var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + 
      '&action=updateList&feuser=14'; 
      $.post("index.php?eID=moveitems", order, 
      function(theResponse){

                               $("#response").html(theResponse);
                               $("#response").slideDown('slow');
                               slideout();  

                          }); 

                     }  

                }).disableSelection();
```

Comment: can someone please give me a hint?